# Change Background image every visit

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have about 50 background images for my site. What i am looking to do is randomly present the user with a different one for every visit. By this i mean they will surf through the site with the same background image during their visit.

After they close the browser and re-visit or come back and visit later, they then are presented with a new random background image. Don't need to save anything on what their previous background image was, just a random new one for each new visit to the site.

Not sure it this can be done with C#, Javascript, JQuery or CSS.

EDIT: I am using ASP.net 4.0 C# for my web app. Thanks

Comment: Learn about cookies or localstorage.

Comment: If it is that random, just pick it random.

Comment: @epascarello - `Don't need to save anything on what their previous background image was`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 But the OP needs to maintain something that says what the current image is for the session. So either a cookie if they are doing it on the clientside, or something on the user's session if they are doing it on the backend. Something needs to be remembered for a short period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it in the Session. Pick it at random when it's not already in the session, it will stay the same as long as they're at your site -- and next time they come back, they'll get a new one.

For example (my C# is a little rusty):

```
public getBackground (HttpSessionState session) {
    String bg = (string) session["session.randomBG"];
    if (bg == null) {
        // pick a random BG & store  it.
        bg = "pick one";
        session["session.randomBG"] = bg;
    }
    return bg;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me with using a some custom code for the random image.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `cookies` as stated in the comments. This will only add extra bandwidth to the header messages sent to the server.

Instead, use local storage in the browser to save what the last image was they used. When a new session is started increment this value, and display the next image.

I've used [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) on projects and it works fine.

You can save the currently shown image in their browsers storage, and maybe a session ID. Later, you can check if the session ID has changed. If so, then change to a different image.

```
var image = $.jStorage.get("image", 0);
var session_id = $.jStorage.get("session", "put current session id here");

if(session_id != "current session id")
{
   image = (image < 50) ? 0 : image+1;
   $.jStorage.set("image",image);
   $.jStorage.set("session","current session id");
}

// use image to set background
```

EDIT:

Don't place this JavaScript in each web page. Instead, place it in a ASP.NET page that responses as a Javascript content type and load it via the page's header. This way page caching on the browser won't affect the script when the session changes.

Comment: What do you think `jStorage` uses when `sessionStorage` isn't available in the browser?

Comment: Why add weight, complexity & possible compatibility issues with JStorage -- when a Session ID is gonna be what, 30-odd bytes? I'd go with the KISS principle, here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [
    "/images01.png",
    "/images02.png",
 ...
];

/*background url*/ = list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length];
```

Comment: This doesn't retain same background for the duration of the visit.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible. I will use pseudo-code here to show you how it could be done. Surely soon examples in Java will appear.

In the beginning of each page:

```
StartSession()
If ! SessionVariable[myBackground] then
    x=Randomize 50
    SessionVariable[myBackground]="image0" + x + ".jpg"
endif

<style>
body {background-image:url(SessionVariable[myBackground];}
</style>
```

Make sure you use the style tag where appropriate. The SessionVariable[myBackground] is user-created. In PHP it would look like this:

```
$_SESSION['myBackground']
```

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
/** 
 * Change background image hourly. 
 * Name your images with 0.jpg, 1.jpg, ..., 49.jpg.
 */
function getBackground2() {
  var expires = 3600000,
      numOfImages = 50,
      seed = Math.round(Date.now() / expires % numOfImages);
  return '/path/to/background/' + seed + '.jpg';
}
```